# Code documentation stopped working in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode6, code-documentation

I waited until 6.0.1 to switch to Xcode 6. Upon opening one of my project, I noticed that the quick help view of a method or variable's documentation doesn't work anymore.

For example a simple:

```
/*! Value of the property. */
```

for a `@property` just causes Xcode to say 'Declared in' when trying to view the doc by option clicking on a use of the property somewhere in the code instead of displaying the documentation itself.

Cocoa's own classes doc still display fine and I can tell my documentation gets parsed as incorrectly naming a `@param` will still cause a warning.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting all the stuff cached in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData fixed the issue.